# Where does "The Edge Of Time" fit into The Doctor Who TV canon?

Tags: doctor-who, canon

According to internet news reports the VR game, *Doctor Who: The Edge Of Time*, even voiced by Jodie Whitaker herself is canon to the TV series.

So where does *The Edge Of Time* fit into the *Doctor Who* TV canon? As in what particular episode is it supposed to be set after or before?

Answer (score 1):

According to the creators of the game, it sits between Season 11 and Season 12.

> **Q.** **And do you have to pick a point where it fits in the canon and things like that?**
>
> **Ian Hambleton:** *Yeah, we got asked this the other day. I think it fits post-the-last-series. This is almost existing between the two series* [series 11 and series 12], *basically.*
>
> **Russell Harding:** *And the showrunners have always said about it being in ‘the inbetween’.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Doctor Who: The Edge Of Time interview – VR team talk Jodie Whittaker, Weeping Angels and more](https://www.denofgeek.com/games/doctor-who-the-edge-of-time-interview-vr-team-talk-jodie-whittaker-weeping-angels-and-more/)</sup></sub>

Interestingly the game's producer Kiron Ramdewar was much more cagey. It's described by him as a "standalone episode" that doesn't directly tie-in to the show.

> **Q: So does this tie into the new season of the show at all?**
>
> So we're working with the BBC on this and then obviously, like I said, Jodie's done all the voice work for it and I would kind of see it as its own standalone episode almost, so while **it doesn't directly tie-in with the latest season [season 12], it's set within the same universe and world and the dots that Jodie's in at the moment**
>
> <sub><sup>[Doctor Who: The Edge Of Time - Gameplay Interview](https://youtu.be/pcqW5U0FFi4?t=136)</sup></sub>

Comment: So it's essentially the 2019 Dr. Who Christmas Special that they didn't bother to produce ...?

Comment: @Jeeped - It's just a bit of fluff. A standalone episode featuring Doctor Jodie (only) that has no bearing on the show and will never be mentioned on the show.

Answer (score 0):

Its set directly after resolution the doctor finishes being with her companions and is set before the 2020 series when she then goes to do what she does do.

Comment: Can you add some supporting evidence to your answer - like a quotation?